# How to freeze/lock a single row in an ExtJs grid?

Tags: extjs4.1

I want to be able to freeze/lock the last row in my grid so that it is always visible at the bottom while scrolling vertically, just like it is possible to do so for columns eg: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/grid/locking-grid.html. Is there a way to do so in Ext?Id appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you looked at `Ext.grid.feature.Summary` ? Most cases i can imagine wanting to doc a row at the bottom, summary is a much better fit.

Comment: Yeah, ive looked at it but it doesnt freeze the row while scrolling

Comment: @Armaan: Did u get any solution to this? I also need it

Comment: @1355: Nope, we did it via creating a separate grid just for the last row and then synchronizing the column widths if the main grid's columns are re-sized and also had to hide the grids scroll bar and sync the horizontal scrolling.

Comment: I face same problem @Armaan If you will get this solution please post your ans

Answer (score 5):

In the grid config, where you specify the plugin

```js
features: [{
    ftype: 'summary',
    dock: 'top'
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I might came here in a huge delay, but after I couldn't find anything online I thought it could be good if I posted my findings..
As of extjs4.2 a config option named 'dock' does the job. So: `dock: 'bottom'` would be perfect for this, same goes for `'top'`!

Comment: Where do you put this config? `dock:'bottom'`

Comment: @ tsippert you should add this like so inside the grid config:  features: [
                    {
                        ftype: 'summary',
                        dock: 'bottom'
                    }
                ],